OpenAPI schema not derived for function
I cannot seem to get swagger to derive the schema for my endpoint if it is defined as a function rather than as a lambda:
static async Task<IResult> State(Runner runner)
{
    var simulation = await runner.GetState();
    var state = new State
    {
        Iteration = simulation.Iteration,
        SimTime = simulation.SimTime,
        Population = simulation.Population.People.Count,
        Companies = simulation.Businesses.All.Count,
        Balance = simulation.DevelopmentCouncil.Cash
    };
    return TypedResults.Ok(state);
}

app.MapGet("/state", State);

produces:
"/state": {
    "get": {
        "tags": [
        "Server"
            ],
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "Success"
            }
        }
    }
}

Meanwhile if I define it inline as a lambda:
app.MapGet("/state2", async () =>
{
    var simulation = await runner.GetState();
    var state = new State
    {
        Iteration = simulation.Iteration,
        SimTime = simulation.SimTime,
        Population = simulation.Population.People.Count,
        Companies = simulation.Businesses.All.Count,
        Balance = simulation.DevelopmentCouncil.Cash
    };
    return TypedResults.Ok(state);
});

it produces
"/state2": {
    "get": {
        "tags": [
        "EDCDaemon"
            ],
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "Success",
                "content": {
                    "application/json": {
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/State"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

plus the referenced schema in components.
